# Не работает <TextAlign>Justify</TextAlign>

Tags: css

Добрый день.
Есть кусочек следующего отчета:

```
<Paragraphs>
      <Paragraph>
        <TextRuns>
          <TextRun>
            <Value>---Текст---Value>
            <Style>
              <FontStyle>Normal</FontStyle>
              <FontFamily>Times New Roman</FontFamily>
              <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
              <FontWeight>Normal</FontWeight>
              <TextDecoration>None</TextDecoration>
              <Color>#000000</Color>
            </Style>
          </TextRun>
        </TextRuns>
        <HangingIndent>1cm</HangingIndent>
        <Style>
          <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
        </Style>
      </Paragraph>
      <Paragraph>
        <TextRuns>
          <TextRun>
            <Value>---Текст---</Value>
            <Style>
              <FontStyle>Normal</FontStyle>
              <FontFamily>Times New Roman</FontFamily>
              <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
              <FontWeight>Normal</FontWeight>
              <TextDecoration>None</TextDecoration>
              <Color>#000000</Color>
            </Style>
          </TextRun>
        </TextRuns>
        <LeftIndent>0cm</LeftIndent>
        <RightIndent>0cm</RightIndent>
        <HangingIndent>1cm</HangingIndent>
        <Style>
          <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
        </Style>
      </Paragraph>
    </Paragraphs>
```

Требуется сделать выравнивание по ширине страницы текста. Но если использую Justify то среда бракует отчет и он не отрабатывает. Подскажите, что можно придумать?

Comment: Что это за код? XML? Кто обрабатывает тег `<TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>`? Может оно просто не знает про `Justify `.

Comment: да, xml. обработка отчета dynamic crm. в том и вопрос, что если он его не понимает, каким аналогом можно заменить?

Comment: Нет данной CRM, что бы проверить.  `General` не дает желаемого?

Comment: Ты что-ли псих на XML писать??

Answer (score 1):

С [официального источника](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/f/34/t/140066)

> On the report Text box we have two types of alignments Text Align (left,right, center,general) & Vertical Align(Top, Middle, bottom), we can provide the expressions if we want to change the alignments dynamically, if you are looking for something else, let us know.